# How to format specific char/string to datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

The below string/char is a date format which SQL Server doesn't support, I need to convert this to a `datetime` data type in SQL Server 2008

```
20170202131759
```

This date format consists of year, month, day, hour, min, sec

Comment: substrings are your friend.

Answer (score 1):

`20170602 13:17:59` is a parseable format, to make your string look like that & cast:

```
select cast(stuff(stuff(stuff('20170202131759', 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':') as datetime)
```

(assumes mmdd)

Comment: why result has .ooo in the last part. 2017-02-02 13:17:59.000

Comment: All DATETIMEs do, its for milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

SQL server cannot implicitly convert this string to `DateTime`, you need to insert some characters:

```
Select SUBSTRING('20170202131759',1,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING('20170202131759',5,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING('20170202131759',7,2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING('20170202131759',9,2)+ ':' + SUBSTRING('20170202131759',11,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING('20170202131759',13,2)
```

which will give you this:

`2017-02-02 13:17:59`, then it could be a `DateTime` string

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a given format that isn't one of the built-in ones available for conversion, you'll generally have to "build" one.

This can easily be done using individual [`SUBSTRING()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) function calls or by using the [`STUFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql) function to massage it into a format that is (along with a [`CAST()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) call to actually make it into a `DATETIME`):

```
-- This will grab each section, append necessary separators and cast to a DATETIME
SELECT CAST(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF('20170202131759',13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' ') AS DATETIME)
```

**Example**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This uses `left()` and `substring()` to build the following string format `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss`, and converts that to a `datetime` datatype using `convert()`.

```
declare @str varchar(15)= '20170202131759';

select convert(datetime,
               left(@str,8)+' '
               +substring(@str,9,2)+':'
               +substring(@str,11,2)+':'
               +substring(@str,13,2)
               )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HEJ3250